# What does "obscure the core insight" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "prevent their ability to understand"?
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insight
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obscure?q=obscure+

However, "these qualifiers should not **obscure the core insight**," he wrote. "A large and growing number of countries could quickly take the lead in ending their own extreme income poverty. A mix of domestic and peer country pressure is needed to focus efforts."

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/cash-transfers-to-end-poverty-2017-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These qualifications should not obscure the core insight.

*Obscure* is used here in the sense which your dictionary defines as "prevent something from being seen or heard".

"Insight" is not the act of understanding or the ability to understand but  *result* of understanding, the matter which is understood: that "countries in the developing world could theoretically afford to end poverty tomorrow, just by awarding citizens direct cash transfers."

Mr. McArthur acknowledges several qualifiers to this insight, but says that these qualifiers should not hide the the fundamental truth of the insight and prevent policymakers from acting on it.